# How do I convert Regex object to string

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on c# and am grabbing only links (an example) to the downloaded html code.

I know that I have the code of the website in the string htmlcode.

However I can't seem to get this to allow me to put match into a string. Below is my code:

```
 public string getURL()
    {
        /* Web client being opened up and being ready to read */
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        Uri URL = new Uri("http://www.pinkbike.com");
        string htmlcode = webclient.DownloadString(URL);
        /* Time to grab only the links */
        string pattern = @"a href=""(?<link>.+?)""";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection MC = regex.Matches(htmlcode);
        string htmlcode1;
        foreach(Match match in MC)
        {
            /* Error location */
            htmlcode1 = match.Groups["link"];

        }
        return htmlcode1;
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the type of `match.Groups["link"]` is? Does the compiler not tell you the type that you are trying to convert to string thus making it easy to look up in documentation?

Comment: [Don't use Regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)  Consider something like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
 htmlcode1 = match.Groups["link"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also you String function `Contains()`.  instated of using `regex`

`htmlcode1.Contains("Links")`